# Вывести из БД только 100 символов

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, sql-server

Как вывести из бд только 100 символов столбца "Content"? Пробовал использовать Limit и ([Content],100) , но ничего не вышло.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Title], [Content] FROM [News] ORDER BY [Id] DESC ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

-

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="news" > 
       <h3><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' /></h3>
       <asp:Label ID="contentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content") %>' /><br />
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Title], SUBSTRING([Content],0,100) as [Content] FROM [News] ORDER BY [Id]  DESC ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Функция `substring` написана из расчета, что у вас MS SQL Server, для других СУБД функции могут называться по другому. Например для оракла и MySQL функция `SUBSTR` и отсчет символов начинается с 1.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' не содержит свойство с именем content.
И указывает на строчку: 
<asp:Label ID="contentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content") %>' /><br />

Подключение идёт к sql express 2008.

Comment: А до этого такой ошибки как я понимаю не было ... Попробуйте в том запросе что бы было `SUBSTRING([Content],0,100) as [Content]`

Comment: ........Спасибо!!!!